# beginner how to combine code together Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I just started learning JS. I want to put cart1 and cart2 together.

```
if (cart1) {
        for (const key in data) {
          main.push({
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            name: data[key].name
            image: data[key].image
            location: data[key].location,
          });
        }
      }

if (cart2) {
        for (const key in data) {
          main.push({
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            name: data[key].name
            image: data[key].image
          });
        }
      }
```

I used ternary operator, but I don't want cart2 have `location` property

```
if (cart2 || cart1) {
        for (const key in data) {
          main.push({
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            name: data[key].name
            image: data[key].image
            location: cart1? data[key].location : "",
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optionally add a property by adding it to `object` and spreading it optionally.

`...` is the spread operator, which will spread all the properties inside `{ location: data[key].location }` object ( there is only one property which is location ), and that happens only if the `cards` are not a falsy value ( not equal to `null` or `undefined` or a value can be falsy like zero for numbers ) the `&&` operator check value to be truthy.

For more resources.
[AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)
[Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
if (cart2 || cart1) {
        for (const key in data) {
          main.push({
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            name: data[key].name,
            image: data[key].image,
            ...(cart1 && { location: data[key].location }),
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: While that's a valid approach, I think it would be worth explaining how/why this works. There's a good chance a new JS user won't understand what's going on here. (Also, you've copied the missing `,` in the return object from the OP)

Comment: HI mina thx, but why do we need to add ... in front of (cart1 && { location: data[key].location })

Comment: @DBS, I think I already add an explanation, I'm not sure, if you read it or you mean that it's not enough.

Comment: I mean, a new JS user probably doesn't know what `...` does, and potentially doesn't understand how `a && b` results in `b` if `a` is truthy.

Comment: @inthewilddd, I added more explanation about this point to the answer, please check again.

Comment: Also, I add some resources you can read for more details.

Comment: Thx for answering my stupid question.

Comment: No bro, there is no stupid question, on the contrary, it is a good one, have a happy day.

Answer (score 1):

Don't immediately push an object to the array. Create the main object, add a location when necessary, and *then* push the completed object to the array.

```
for (const key in data) {
  const obj = {
    id: Math.random().toString(),
    name: data[key].name
    image: data[key].image
  };
  if (cart1) obj.location = data[key].location;
  main.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const
  data = [{ name:'jo', image:'img', location:'loc'} ]
, main = []
  ;
foo(true,false)
main.length = 0;
foo(false,true)


function foo(cart1,cart2)
  {
  if (cart2 || cart1)
    {
    for (const key in data)
      {
      main.push( Object.assign( {}
        , { id    : Math.random().toString()
          , name  : data[key].name
          , image : data[key].image 
          }
        , cart1 ? { location: data[key].location } : null
        ))
      } 
    }
  // show result
  console.log( {cart1,cart2},':\n', JSON.stringify(main),'\n\n' )
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Thank you.  learned a new method today:)